# Question about כַּבֵּד אֶת אָבִיךָ וְאֶת אִמֶּךָ

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, family-members

I am not a very knowledgeable Jew. I am the product of a mixed marriage (Mom is Jewish/Dad is not). However, I was raised in a Jewish household. Over the years I have leaned more towards observance than non-observance. This is much to my parents chagrin. What if my parents want me to remain a secular Jew and just get married and remain secular. Am I obligated to honor those wishes or should I follow my own path?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @chanan and welcome to Mi Yodeya. It is important to note that in such a sensitive situation you should seek guidance from a competent Rabbinic authority as one has to tread carefully when potentially upsetting one's parents. There are exceptions to the rule but I would advise you first speak to a Rav.

Comment: איש אמו ואביו תיראו ואת שבתתי תשמרו אני יהוהLev 19:3

Comment: For specifics, please consult your local rabbinical leader, but as DoubleAA alludes to, the commentary of Rashi on Lev 19:3 ("AND MY SABBATHS...") gives an answer https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.3?lang=en&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Comment: Just wishing you continued success in your journey, and I hope your parents can accept your desire for growth.

Comment: It is similar to them asking you not to keep shabbos, eat nonkosher food, rob a bank, or go to a church. None of those actions are allowed even if your parents pretend that *respect* for parents should allow you to do them.

Answer (score 1):

Its learned out from  vayikra 19:3 that if your parents tell you to violate the Torah you have no obligation to listen to them. (Kiddushin 30b)